# Не выводит весь результат

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

Моя проблема такова..

Я написал код на языке PHP, указал слово, по которому будет искать город, но почему-то я не могу получить все результаты (80+). У меня выводит только 1 город [Набережные Челны]

```
$word = "казан";
$e = mb_substr($word, mb_strlen($word)-1, 1);
$db = new \SQLite3(__DIR__ . '/citi_bot/citi.db');
$l = mb_strtoupper($e);
$k = $db->query("SELECT Город FROM Лист1 WHERE Город LIKE '$l%'")->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
echo "Word: $l <br>";
echo var_dump($k);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SQLite3Result::fetchArray — Выбирает одну строку из результирующего набора и помещает ее в ассоциативный или нумерованный массив, или в оба сразу` http://php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php#99917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @Visman, `fetchArray` выбирает только одну строку. 
По ссылке  http://php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php в комментариях есть пример, как получить весь результат, применительно к Вашему случаю должно быть примерно так.

```
$word = "казан";
$e = mb_substr($word, mb_strlen($word)-1, 1);
$db = new \SQLite3(__DIR__ . '/citi_bot/citi.db');
$l = mb_strtoupper($e);
$result = $db->query("SELECT Город FROM Лист1 WHERE Город LIKE '$l%'");

$k=array();

while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){ 
          $k[] = $res['Город']; 
} 

echo "Word: $l <br>";
var_dump($k);
```